# Validate row without requiring all rows ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, validation, razor

Currently, all rows require input. This is a problem, because I would like a user to have all the rows displayed in case they need to input a lot of cats, but if a row is blank it shouldn't be an issue.

The desired behavior is that if nothing is filled in for a row, then the row will **not** be required. If `IDNumber` is input in a row, then `Name` is also required, and vice versa.

A constraint is that I cannot install third party libraries to solve this.

How can I create this behavior? Here is my code currently:

Models:

```
public class CatHotel 
{
   public string HotelName { get; set; }
   public CatModel[] Cats { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
public class CatModel 
{ 
   [Required] 
   public string IDNumber { get; set; }
   [Required]
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

CSHTML:

```html
@{ int NumberOfCats = 12; }

@for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfCats; i++)
{
   <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-3">
         <div>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Cats[i].IDNumber,
            new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Cat ID *"})
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2">
         <div>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Cats[i].Name,
            new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Cat Name *"})
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
         <div>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Cats[i].Comment,
            new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Comment" })
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In my opinion, You can just show one `CatModel` input tag at the first, And there is a `+` button under the input, If User want to input more cats, they can click this `+` button, then use javascript to generate another `CatModel` input tag. I think you want `IDNumber` be input in a row, So i think It's not necessary for use to input this value by themselves. when user click `+` button, javascript will generate `IDNumber` hidden input tag with an auto-incremented value.

Comment: Thank you, I've considered that for the UI but I would prefer to have the fields available. I don't want the user to have to click a + sign several times. @XinranShen

Comment: OK, But I'm afraid the default model validation can't achieve it,